# how to merge 2 lists by regex matching in java

Tags: java, regex

I have 2 lists,

```
listA = Amy, Bob, Dan
```

and

```
listB = Amy123, Bob23, Pam92, Dan45, Vince55
```

How do I create a list that contains the values in `listB` that begin with the values in `listA`, using regex?

The result list should look like this:

```
mergedList = Amy123, Bob23, Dan45
```

Comment: what is your approaching in finding mergedList ? If I understand correctly, if an element from ListA is contained in element of ListB then add the element of List B to mergedList, Right?

Comment: It's not clear, on which criteria you want the list elements to be merged. So please try to describe the criteria in more detail. Btw. regex could be one of many solutions to implement the match.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I updated your question to make it a little more clear how you were wanting to use the two lists together to get the "mergeList" that you wanted at the end.  If I did not accurately capture what you are trying to do, please feel free to update the question again to fix the error, but please provide more details about exactly what you want, so that you have a better chance of getting an answer that can help you and others.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In case the matching criterion is that the elements should start with the same string:

```
    List<String> listA = Arrays.asList("Amy", "Bob", "Dan");
    List<String> listB = Arrays.asList("Amy123", "Bob23", "Pam92", "Dan45", "Vince55");

    List<String> mergedList = listB.stream().filter(elementB -> listA.stream().anyMatch(elementA -> elementB.startsWith(elementA))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Don't give complete code answer before OP didn't show any coding progress.It might be a homework

Comment: @RamPrakash That answer is not using a regex.

Answer (score 0):

**My Observation :**

1) You have two lists : listA and listB

2) logic is to match items of listA with listB. If listA item is found(in part using regex or some other method OR as whole) in listB, then push listB item to mergelist, otherwise ignore listB item.

**Heres what you can do :**

1) I am using Java8 lambdas.

2) I havent used regex in this code. I guess you dont really need regex here. After all you basically are searching a string in another string as part or in whole. I have used contains() method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("Amy","Bob","Dan");
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("Amy123","Bob23","Pam92","Dan45","Vince55");
    List<String> mergedList = new ArrayList<>();

    list1.forEach(item1 -> {
        list2.forEach(item2 -> {
            if(item2.contains(item1))
                mergedList.add(item2);
        });
    });

    mergedList.forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

3) The code outputs this :

Amy123
Bob23
Dan45

Comment: Is there a way to do this faster without searching item wise?

Comment: I agree it takes O(n2) time. But the compulsion is each item of each list has to be checked. Sorting both the lists alphabetically and/or deleting the matched items from listB may speed it up a tad.

Comment: Or you could convert the list to a stream and call parallel() method on it and then do this operation. This enables the stream to be operated by JVM managed threads that will significantly increase the speed !